# QnA maker versioning

Tags: botframework, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, azure-qna-maker

I am hoping to use QnA maker to facilitate the simple question and answer feature of my chatbot, and use LUIS for more complex intents like extracting entities from sentences for questions that require more context.

With LUIS, it's possible to publish different versions of your app to either production or staging. It's also possible to clone and import versions. I would like to also do this with QnA Maker. Is it possible or a feature that will be added in the future?

I know its possible to download a knowledge base from QnA maker in tsv format, you can only publish to 1 endpoint as far as I know

Answer (score 3):

No it's not currently possible, the only possibility currently is to setup several QnAMaker services and switch between them on your code.

You only need 1 QnAMaker Dialog but you will have to change the way of passing the parameters (KbId and Subscription Key):

From your routing dialog:

```
await context.Forward(new BasicQnAMakerDialog(this._qnaSubscriptionKey, this._qnaKnowledgeBaseId, this._qnaNoMatchMessage, 0.5), QnaDialogResume, incomingMessage);
```

And the start of the BasicQnAMakerDialog implementation:

```
[Serializable]
public class BasicQnAMakerDialog : QnAMakerDialog
{
    public BasicQnAMakerDialog(string subscriptionKey, string kbId, string noMatchString, double minScore) : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(subscriptionKey, kbId, noMatchString, minScore))) { }
```

Comment: If that reply was helpful, please don't forget to accept it, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your solution however I want to use the same QnA Maker service for 2 bots (a test bot and production bot), but have 2 versions of the service. My only work around at the minute is yes to have 2 QnA Maker services, but to export the knowledge base from the 'Test Service' and replace the 'Production Service' with the exported Test Service KB

Comment: There's currently no versioning in QnAMaker projects as I said, sorry