# Version control possible in QnA maker?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

Currently, I am working in a FAQ bot, I have to include QnA pair each time when I get a new question related to the particular topic. Is it possible to revert to previous version if a particular QnA pair is not needed? This is the case, If I have added some hundred QnA pairs and I don't want it, Can I revert to previous version. From the [QnA maker versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47795755/qna-maker-versioning) its saying its not possible. As this is an earlier post, still that feature not present or in future there is a plan to include?

Also I know .tsv,.csv etc can be uploaded each time. Is there a provision to revert to previous version of QnA pair in QnA maker?

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer:

No, it has not changed since 2017. For plans to include it, I don't know, and there is no "iteration" or "version" in QnA Maker app.

---

### Long answer:

But with some development, you can handle it.

You can see the list of API methods available for QnA Maker knowledge base management: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/

In particular, you can focus on `Update Knowledgebase` method [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/5ac266295b4ccd1554da7600): as you can see in its body sample, there is a `delete` block:

```
{
  "add": {
    "qnaList": [],
    "urls": [],
    "files": []
  },
  "delete": {
    "ids": [
      4,
      13,
      35
    ],
    "sources": [
      "Custom Editorial"
    ]
  },
  "update": { ... }
}
```

So you can use this method to "rollback" the entries that you added previously.

But be careful, b**ecause you have to use the `id` fields and they are not matching the `id` field used when you are using `add`**.

> Also I know .tsv,.csv etc can be uploaded each time. Is there a
>   provision to revert to previous version of QnA pair in QnA maker?

That may be a good option for quick rollback, if you save your KB every time before a modification, because you will not need to process the ID as mentioned above.